# Tanuki Software Wrapper unable to be customized

Tags: java, jar, windows-services, wrapper

I am wrapping a java application via Tanuki Software Wrapper [Tanuki Software Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/customize.html) for making windows service and it is working fine and then after i want to customize this as per its documentation given on [Customizing Application (Windows)](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/customize.html). As per documentation when i run the following command

```
wrapperw.exe --customize --icon MyIcon.ico --splash MySplash.bmp --target MyApp.exe --manufacturer "My Organization Name" --passthrough
```

The following error is come

`FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:45 | encountered a fatal error in Wrapper
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:45 |   exceptionCode    = EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:45 |   exceptionFlag    = EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE_EXCEPTION
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:45 |   exceptionAddress = 76EA4123
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:45 |   Read access exception from 4942F3B0
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:45 |   Wrapper Main Loop Status:
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:45 |     Current Ticks: 0xfffffe00
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:45 |     Wrapper State: STARTING
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:45 |     Java State: DOWN_CLEAN (Timeout: 0x00000000)
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:45 |     Exit Requested: false
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:45 |     Restart Mode: 1
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:45 |   Writing dump file: C:\Users\USER4\Desktop\Webmuch_Service_Netbean\WMPCB\WMPCB\src\WebmuchService\bin\wrapper-windows-x86-32-3.5.25-pro-20141029132345-5484-4544.dmp
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:46 |     Dump completed.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:46 |   Please send the dump file to support@tanukisoftware.com along with
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:46 |     your wrapper.conf and wrapper.log files.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:46 | --------------------------------------------------------------------
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2014/10/29 13:23:46 | <-- Wrapper Stopping due to error`

I do't know what i am doing wrong , but it is seeming licences problem but if it would be licence problem my wrapper would also not work .

**Whether any other better service wrapper is available which is free ?**

If any have idea please help me .

Thanks a lot ..

Comment: I can't help you for your problem with this service Wrapper, but I use a free tool named JavaExe, for many years ago...and its works fine (but it working only for Windows)

Comment: I have now used Common Daemon Apache wrapper instead if Tanuki because Common Daemon Apache is free and easy to implement and more flexible .